# How do I balance this?

Tags: statistics

I'm making a voting system.

Person A chooses a value between 0 and 100 of how much A agrees(100) with the question.

Other people "B" guess where the most people will put their votes.

Any value within +/- 25 from B gives a positive score, otherwise the score is negative. The closer A is to B, the higher score B gets.

The problem is at the edges. If B puts their guess at 100 they will only cover the range 75-100, while someone putting their guess at 75 would cover 50-100. Sure, 100 would give optimal score if A guesses 100, but there has to be some guess between 75 and 100 that is better on average.

How do I design a function so that no matter where B guesses, the average score given for any A will be the same?

(f(x) = 0 doesn't count)

Please change the tags, I have no clue what to tag this with.

Comment: Why don't you just change guesses that are for example $\geq 75$ to $75$? Because as you already saw it makes no sense to guess anything over $75$.

Comment: For a guess A=100 it makes a lot of difference. B=100 gives a max score and B=75 gives zero score, but no negative score either. Point is, the interval is bigger so on average it should have a higher yield. That's what I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

First, is it a problem?  You could just tell people what the rules are without the "correction" and let them factor that into their predictions.

Second, are all the negative scores for being over $25$ off the same or does the score get more negative as you get further away.  In that case, you don't just have an end effect, guessing $50$ will give a better average score than anything else (assuming the points are symmetric in the miss distance).

Third, there are many ways to do this.  Here is one stupid one.  Let the average score  you want be $N$.  Define the score for missing as $f(|A-B|)$ for $A \neq B$, which you already have.  Then the score for being exactly right is $g(B)=101N-\sum_{A \neq B}f(|A-B|)$